# Rockettheme: Kinetic - making banner full width

Tags: joomla

I dont know what kind of success i'll have from this post but struggling at the moment to get a reply on the rockettheme forums.

I have downloaded this template (Kinetic) from Rockettheme.com (demo below;)
http://demo.rockettheme.com/?template=kinetic

I have changed it to come out looking like the link below;

http://evolve.gen.nz/

However im really struggling to differentiate the footer from the rest of the website. Im looking at changing it to a light grey however I cannot make it stretch right across the website as the footer is located in the container and stops at either edge of the container.

is there anyway to make a footer colour go right across the page?

(the same as the following website, if you go down to the bottom of the page and you will see a dark grey, charcoal colour)

http://www.colmanweb.co.nz/websites/refuge/

Any ideas on how I could get this achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to edit the index.php file of the template, should be at `templates/kinetic/index.php` roughly. If you head to the bottom, you will find a div with `rt-footer`. You will want to pull this entire div statement out and paste it outside of the div with an id `rt-surround`. Your best bet is to find `rt-debug` and paste it just above.

I run a lot of sites off the base gantry template from Rocket Theme and do this type of thing often, so it should work.

Two issues you may run into. If you don't get the right closing div tag, you can get some weird output if the divs aren't closed properly. So be careful and use the indentation to help you.

Second, there may be some css styling that is specific to the old heirarchy. I doubt it in this case, but it can happen. You may have to fix some of the css styling.

Comment: Thanks David, I tried what and it works just need to play around with footer modules.

Comment: It's probably better practice to override the rt-surround styling in the custom css file that Gantry makes provision for. This way, template updates will not overwrite your changes.